# how to use CASE when then in sql?

Tags: python, sql, django, case

i have an sql query that crash the program i want to check if the field contain 0 or 1 so i used :

```
query = cursor.execute('select ID, CASE WHEN status = 1 THEN "GOOD" WHEN status = 0 THEN "BAD" END AS status FROM Person')
```

the error is below :

> invalid column name "GOOD" invalid column name "BAD"

Comment: Use single quotes for strings in SQL.  I am voting to close as a typographical error.

Comment: Use single quotes for string literals. Double quotes are for delimited identifiers, like `"Column Name"`.

Comment: if i use single code it will crash due to syntax error

Comment: *if i use single code it will crash due to syntax error* - switch the string to use double quotes, i.e. `"select... FROM Person"` or triple quotes i.e. `'''select... FROM Person'''`. If you use single quotes then you need to escape single quotes with a backslash which is tricker, i.e. `'select ID, CASE WHEN status = 1 THEN \'GOOD\'...'`.

Comment: @Alasdair. I see. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Python can take either single quote or double quote for strings.  Try this:

```py
query = cursor.execute("select ID, CASE WHEN status = 1 THEN 'GOOD' WHEN status = 0 THEN 'BAD' END AS status FROM Person")
```

You can also change your `CASE` to this:

`CASE status WHEN 1 THEN 'GOOD' WHEN 0 THEN 'BAD' END`

Answer (score 0):

You have to change it this way

```
select ID, CASE status  when 1 then 'GOOD' when 2 then 'BAD' END as STATUS from Person
```

In SQL it works as follows;
'case' column to review
'when' condition start
'then'
'end'
You can add 'else' if you want.